# parsing c++ in python

Tags: python, c++, parsing, python-3.x

I'm looking to parse c++ code files in python. I'm mostly concerned with only the function declarations, not the definitions.
The kind of output GCCXML gives seems perfect to me but the thing is I can't get GCCXML to work, I can't find proper documentation. All the articles I found online are old and possibly outdated.

Can anyone suggest any other alternative? Or and updated links regarding GCCXML.

I'm using Python 3.4.2 and IDLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/): it provides a library which provides full access to the compilers AST. I seem to recall there was a python binding but I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1):

Clang has an API that can be used for code completion and more, AFAIK, with python bindings.